# Multi tenant architecture and NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, saas

Could anyone explain me finally what is the best strategy to implement transparent and fluent support of multi-tenant functionality in NHibernate powered domain model?

Im looking for the way, how to keep the domain logic as isolated as possible from the  multi-tenant stuff like filtering by TenantID etc

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use different databases for each client.

Implementing multi-tenanting in this manner allows you to effectively write a single tenant application and only worry about the multi-tenanting at the point where you create / retrieve the session.

I haven't delved deep into the details as yet (I need to do something similar in a few months), but I think the easiest way to manage which database a session is connected to is via a custom ISessionFactory implementation that can determine which connection to use (based on an external aspect such as the host portion of the request url).

I have seen at least one post around the net somewhere discussing this, but I cannot find the link at this time.

If you are using Castle Windsor, have a look at the NHibernate integration facility.  This supports the concept of multiple ( named ) session factories which would allow you to have a session factory per client.  The integration facility provides an ISessionManager interface which allows you to open a session on a named session factory ( as well as providing per request session semantics for web applications ).  Anything requiring access to the session could simply take an ISession constructor parameter and you could create a factory that takes an ISessionManager as a constructor parameter.  You factory could then open a session on the appropriate named session factory by inspecting the request to determine which named session factory should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been digging into it for my next project recently.
You can implement custom IConnectionProvider and register it in configuration with "connection.provider".

I suggest you derive from DriverConnectionProvider and override ConnectionString rather then implement a completely custom one.

It can be something like this one:

```
    public class ContextualConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
    {

        protected override string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCurrentTenantDatabaseConnectionStringInternally();
            }
        }

        public override void Configure(IDictionary<string, string> settings)
        {
            ConfigureDriver(settings);
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Ayende](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/06/Multi-Tenancy.aspx) has some good blog posts about building multi-tenancy apps. How NHibernate is used for it would depend on the type of multi-tenancy you are going for.

Comment: Well, Im talking about simple shared database/schema approach: most of tables have special tenant identifying column. But on the domain model level I wouldn't like to see any of these properties

Comment: Hmm....in this case I am not sure, but I do know that an NHibernate session allows you to set filters, but I am not sure exactly how they work. I believe they allow you to run queries and load entities without putting the filter in the queries themselves. This MAY be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shared schema approach requires you to intercept and decorate all of your queries with additional information to restrict the results.

NHibernate provides interceptors to do this, and event listeners are also available from NHibernate 2.0 Aplpha 1.

See http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/15/implementing-nhibernate-interceptors/ and http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/04/nhibernate-20-events-and-listeners.html for discussions on these.

Also have a look at Ayende's Rhino Security component as he does a lot of work in this to modify queries with additional restrictions based on security descriptors.  You can browse the source at https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/security